# Contar caracteres de un String

Tags: python

es correcto contar caracteres de un string de la siguiente forma:

```
cadena = "este es un texto de prueba"
total_caracteres = len(cadena)
print total_caracteres
```

ahora la duda surge cuando tengo un texto con promedio de 10.000 caracteres o mas es decir deseo contar tanto todo incluido espacios en blanco.
quiza alguna guia o es correcto mi forma de contarlos.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No hay diferencia entre contar 20 o 10000 caracteres. El método es el mismo, `len()`. Ahora bien, si estás usando python2 ten en cuenta que eso contará bytes y no caracteres. No son lo mismo si el texto contiene acentos o eñes en utf8. Te recomiendo usar python3. Si lo que te preocupa es guardar en memoria una cadena tan larga, puedes leer un fichero por líneas (pues supongo que los datos están en fichero) e ir sumando la longitud de cada línea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depende de varias condiciones, hay una excelente respuesta [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37262373/6836377)

### Python 3.*:

**A.** Para contar el número de caracteres en un objeto `str`, podemos usar la función `len()`:

```
>>> print(len('please anwser my question'))
25
```

**B.** Para obtener el tamaño reservado en bytes para almacenar el objeto `str`, se puede usar `sys.getsizeof()`:

```
>>> from sys import getsizeof
>>> print(getsizeof('please anwser my question'))
50
```

### Python 2.*:

Es un poco más complicado para Python 2.*.

**A.** La función `len()` en Python 2 retorna la cantidad de bytes reservados para almacenar los *caracteres codificados* en un objeto `str`.

Algunas veces funcionará bien:

```
>>> print(len('abc'))
3
```

Pero otra no:

```
>>> print(len('йцы')) # La cadena tiene tres caracteres cyrillicos
6
```

Esto se debe a que `str` almacena una [codificación de caracteres de longitud variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_code). Entonces, para contar realmente los caracteres hay que saber primero, que codificación se esta usando en el objeto `str`. Entonces, sí es posible convertir la cadena a un objeto [`unicode`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) y obtener la cantidad de caracteres con `len()`:

```
>>> print(len('йцы'.decode('utf8'))) # La cadena tiene tres caracteres cyrillicos
3
```

**B.** La función `sys.getsizeof()` hace lo mismo que en Python 3 - retorna la cantidad de bytes alocados para almacenar la cadena completa.

```
>>> print(getsizeof('йцы'))
27
>>> print(getsizeof('йцы'.decode('utf8')))
32
```